# What is a better way to scroll row of a clarity datagrid to top and expand it programmatically?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

Given ID of a row in clr-datagrid, is there a better way to scroll to and expand that row programmatically than what is mentioned below?

**Side note:** I tried to make Angular Material's cdk-virtual-scroll work with clr-datagrid, to be able to use its `scrollTo` method but seems like it cannot be use with clr-datagrid.

Once specified row is scrolled to top in the datagrid, I can most likely use `clrIfExpanded` to expand it though.

For scrolling, I am currently doing something like following and it works but I would like to know, if there is better way. Please mention your thoughts in comments or answers.

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
.
.
.
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document) { }
  .
  .
  .
  const id = document.getElementById('b1374854-7e93-423d-b571-83f5906e61e3');
  if (id) {
    id.scrollIntoView();
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```